# How to separate comma separated data from csv file?

Tags: python

I have opened a csv file and I want to sort each string which is comma separated and are in same line:

ex:: file :

```
name,sal,dept
tom,10000,it
```

o/p :: each string in string variable

I have a file which is already open, so I can not use "open" API, I have to use "csv.reader" which have to read one line at a time.

Comment: @Rahul, I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're asking. Could you provide block-quoted examples of your input and the desired output?

Comment: Are you asking how to use csv?  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html  What's wrong with the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

If the file open for reading is bound to a variable name, say `fin`; and assuming you're using Python 2.6, and you know the file's not empty (has at least the row with headers):

```
 import csv

 rd = csv.reader(fin)
 headers = next(rd)
 for data in rd:
   ...process data and headers...
```

In Python 2.5, use `headers = rd.next()` instead of `headers = next(rd)`.

These versions use a list of fields `data`, which is a completely general solution (i.e., you don't need to know in advance how many columns the file has: you'll access them as `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc, and the current row has `len(data)` fields at each leg of the loop).

If you know the file has exactly three columns and prefer to use separate names for a variable per column, change the loop header to:

```
 for name, sales, department in rd:
```

The field data as returned by the reader (just like the headers) are all strings.  If you know for example that the second column is an int and want to treat it as such, start the loop with

```
 for data in rd:
     data[1] = int(data[1])
```

or, if you're using the named-variables variant:

```
 for name, sales, department in rd:
     sales = int(sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have properly understood your question. You may want to have a look at the **split** function described in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) anyway.

Comment: i just want to get the data from csv file line byline as my first line  of file contain field names and after that all line contain data.